# 400 Bad Request When Publishing a user's score through Facebook SDK for Unity

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I am using Unity3D 4.3.4 Editor and Facebook SDK for Unity 5.1 which allows for testing inside the Editor. I am able to suceesfully post screenshots of my game, but I am struggling trying to post a score.

I based my code on this two samples:
[Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.API)
and
[Facebook SDK Unity Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/unity/unity-tutorial)
. In the callback method when I inspect the result object, I get:

400 Bad Request

If I change the method from POST to GET, I don't get the error, but the score is not posted either. But at least I know the score and access_token are being sent.

Here is what the Proxy (Fiddler) captures, but I was unable to capture the POST, only the GET.

GET /me/scores?score=89&access_token=CAAIx1MAZCucgBAEh8LvPA5A4JGuUBSAre0WGhQRZC11WHEgFh1KQJNnsbOEjN5ppeqfumfazmS6CIrZCRlJEKNVhU9wtZCJJ66d3sJqBQYyAbSpBnNIrLN70hJ91uJbEXRD1HwITbViziv9ZC1vhLleyKOILrN97DItP1DnGbzP0y0xoKmVA4RN42Shb716EUEY49wZBlsXXXXXX& HTTP/1.1

Here is my code:

```
private IEnumerator PostHighScore() 
{
yield return 0;
int highScore;
highScore = (int)LevelGenerator.Instance.distance;
Dictionary<string, string> wwwForm = new Dictionary<string, string>();
wwwForm["score"] = highScore.ToString();
Log("Just about to POST to /me/scores");
FB.API("/me/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, PostHighScoreCallback, wwwForm);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem. It was very hard to figure it out because the result object of type FBResult only exposes only 3 properties: A string Text that was coming empty, an Image in the form of a Texture2D also empty and a string Error that only showed "400 Bad Request". I was unable to intercept the response on my proxy Fiddler.
See here for more info on  [FBResult](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/DelegateTypes/)

Luckily Mono Developer allowed me to see the private parts of the FBResult object and expanding the data I found a property called responseHeaderString which showed a more detailed error returned on the header.

The error was:

WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#3) Method allowed only for games"

From there I easily found that I needed to go to my App Details on Facebook and change the Category to Games. Since my Facebook was in Spanish, when I created my App I had chosen Entertainment since "Juegos" was not listed, you need to scroll and it is not obvious.

I wanted to share this information since even though you may be facing a completely different problem, knowing that inspecting the FBResult object from Mono Developer will help you find out the reason in the response headers.

Comment: I was stuck on the same problem and your post unstuck me :D
Thank you so much!